# ¿Se pueden copiar todos los valores de una clase CSS a otra con JQuery o JS? (Todas de una vez)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Me guastaría saber si se puede hacer algo así con JQuery o JS:

```
.clase1, .clase2
{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
```

El tema es que la clase1 no fue declarada en CSS. Fue declarada con JQuery así:

```
 $(".clase1").css("width","500px");
 $(".clase1").css("height","300px");
```

Y me gustaría copiar todos sus valores a otra. Es decir, sé que se puede hacer esto:

```
w = $(".clase1").css("width");
$(".clase2").css("width",w);
```

Pero no lo veo muy práctico... la pregunta es si se puede copiar todas las propiedades de una vez sin tener que ir copiando propiedad por propiedad.

Comment: Podrías echarle un vistazo a la función **getComputedStyle()** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Muchas gracias @PHPMyguel. Tiene buena pinta... creo que me va a servir.. voy a probarlo!!

Comment: ¿El archivo `.css` no está a tu alcance para poder editarlo, agregando `.clase1`
?

Comment: Si lo tengo, pero no me sirve.  Lo que pasa es que necesito hacer varias instancias de un objeto y precisamente lo quiero hacer dínamico para no tener que hacer un archivo .css y otro .js para cada objeto. Los objetos no pueen tener el mismo nombre de clase... a ver si puedo hacer algo general que me funcione para las dos instancias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentan por ahí arriba, puedes utilizar `window.getComputedStyle()` para recoger las propiedades y valores de los estilos de un elemento. Aquí tienes un par de métodos que te pueden solucionar el problema y cómo utilizarlos:

```js
/**
 * @param {Element} el Elemento html único
 */
const GetStyles = el => {
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    const rules = [];
    for(let style of styles){
        rules.push({
            [style]: styles.getPropertyValue(style)
        });
    }
    return rules;
};

/**
 * @param {string} selector Selector, pej: #midiv, .miclase
 * @param {Array} rules Array generado por GetStyles()
 */
const ApplyStyles = (selector, rules) => {
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => {
        rules.forEach(rule => {
     for( let [key, value] of Object.entries(rule) ){
                el.style[key] = value;
     }
        });
    });
};

// añadimos algunos divs vacíos
for( let i = 0; i < 50; i++ ){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div></div>';
}

// recogemos los estilos de div.class1
const rules = GetStyles(document.querySelector('.class1'));

// aplicamos los estilos al resto de divs
ApplyStyles('div:not(.class1)', rules);
```

```css
.class1 { display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; background: red; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="class1"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt6swno5/)

Comment: Awesome!! Muchas gracias @jsFiddle